# limit result of simple_html_dom parser to only the first occurence

Tags: php, dom, simple-html-dom

```
require_once('simple_html_dom.php'); 
require_once('url_to_absolute.php');
$html = file_get_html($GLOBALS["AL_CFG"]["siteURL"].'/articles/' . $PageData['ArticleID'] .'/print/');
foreach($html->find('img') as $element) {
// echo $element->src, "\n" . "<br>";
$MetaImage1 = $element->src;
$MetaImage = $MetaImage1;
```

Code above works fine - As results I get all the images on the page, altough :
I would like to limit to the first one only. Thanks for your help.

(my php skills are very limited, please be specific. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1, use the second parameter of `find` (zero based):

```
$element = $html->find('img',0);
echo '<pre>',print_r($element),'</pre>';
```

or 2, `break` out of the `foreach` after 1 occurance:

```
foreach($html->find('img') as $element) {
    // echo $element->src, "\n" . "<br>";
    $MetaImage1 = $element->src;
    $MetaImage = $MetaImage1;
    break;
}
```